# top level await : issue with the solution to connect to mongo db before starting the express server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, async-await, jestjs

I have an express server where I connect to a mongodb before starting the server. I am using a solution that I don't think it is optimal.

connection to database, as you can see from the code below I am using `top level Await` and that is what is causing the problem

```
import mongodb from "mongodb"

let db = {}

const main = async () => {
  try {
    db = await mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

await main()

export default db
```

after connecting to the DB I start the server

```
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()

const opts = {
  port: process.env.PORT || 4000,
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.FRONTENDURL,
    credentials: true
  }
}

// we are awaiting the DB connection and then importing and executing the server
// in dynamic import you need to use default

import("./db.js").then(db => {
  import("./server.js").then(server => {
    server.default.start(opts, t => {
      console.log(`server is up ${opts.port}`)
    })
  })
})
```

this solution is working fine , but in the Jest testing  environment it give me the error `you can not use await outside of an async function` is there a way that jest could accept new feature like `top level await` . or should I reform my solution in order to remove the `top level await`

Comment: Show the test code.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](http://%20https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_top_level_await) suggests, top-level `await` works in native ES modules. The way it works doesn't allow to efficiently use it with CommonJS modules, existing [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-top-level-await) is supposed to be used with bundlers.

Jest uses CommonJS modules by default, ESM support is currently lacking, so top-level `await` can be rewritten in a way that conforms module interop, i.e. exporting a promise of the result:

```
...
export default main().then(() => db)
```

Also catching an error in `main` results in errors later because `db` can be empty object that doesn't have properties it's supposed to.